# from_json silently drops undefined fields

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading json data from Kafka using Spark. I can convert the json data to a spark struct using `from_json()`. When calling `from_json()` I have to specify the schema of the json.

I would like to make sure that the code fails if there are any fields in the json which I did not specify in the schema, but `from_json()` silently drops those fields.

I've tried to set the mode to "FAILFAST" but this didn't change the behavior.

I would have expected the following code to throw an error or create a corrupt record message.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t

data = [
    {
        "data": '{"key1": "value", "key2": "value"}',
    },
]

schema = t.StructType(
        [
            t.StructField("key1", t.StringType()),
            t.StructField("corrupt", t.StringType()),
        ]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data)

df = df.withColumn("data", f.from_json("data", schema, options={
    "mode": "FAILFAST",
    "columnNameOfCorruptRecord": "corrupt"
}))

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- corrupt: string (nullable = true)

+-------------+
|         data|
+-------------+
|{value, NULL}|
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a corrupt record when Spark handles JSON string. [Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/bad-records.html) gives example of what corrupt data is (missing bracket).

For example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .getOrCreate()


data = [
    {
        "data": """{"key1": "value", "key2": "value\"""", # missing a close bracket here
    },
]

schema = t.StructType(
        [
            t.StructField("key1", t.StringType()),
            t.StructField("corrupt", t.StringType()),
        ]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data)
df.printSchema()
df.show(1, False)

df = df.withColumn("data", f.from_json("data", schema, options={
    "mode": "FAILFAST",
    "columnNameOfCorruptRecord": "corrupt"
}))

df.printSchema()
df.show(1, False)
```

The output should be:

```
root
 |-- data: string (nullable = true)

+---------------------------------+
|data                             |
+---------------------------------+
|{"key1": "value", "key2": "value"|
+---------------------------------+

root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- corrupt: string (nullable = true)

24/01/17 17:56:46 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 59)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Malformed records are detected in record parsing. Parse Mode: FAILFAST. To process malformed records as null result, try setting the option 'mode' as 'PERMISSIVE'.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.malformedRecordsDetectedInRecordParsingError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1417)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.FailureSafeParser.parse(FailureSafeParser.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.JsonToStructs.nullSafeEval(jsonExpressions.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnaryExpression.eval(Expression.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.Cast_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.BadRecordException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (InputStreamReader); line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (InputStreamReader); line: 1, column: 34]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JacksonParser.parse(JacksonParser.scala:513)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.JsonToStructs.$anonfun$parser$3(jsonExpressions.scala:608)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.FailureSafeParser.parse(FailureSafeParser.scala:60)
    ... 20 more
```

To achieve your goal, you might need to use external python package like `jsonschema` with UDF.